# How to make CustomValidators fire at the same time as RequiredFieldValidators

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a form containing both CustomValidators and RequiredFieldValidators.

The Custom Validation doesn't fire until all of the requiredFieldValidators have passed.

Can someone tell me how to get them to validate at the same time? I want all the validation messages to show when no data is input.

Comment: Honestly, what are you validating using custom validators  before any data is input?? You cannot say "invalid input" before anything is input, can you? All you can say is "provide an input" at that stage.

Comment: It's an uploadcontrol that can't have a requiredFieldValidator because they don't work with this type of control. The messages from the requiredFieldValidator display but the custom ones won't until all the required ones are fulfilled

Comment: Have you written a client-side validation function for your CustomValidator control? If not, the RequiredFieldValidators are firing first because they have client-side logic that runs before the postback...

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the info. That clears up why it is happening. I'm not allowed to use Javascript for the site. Is there any other way of making them fire at the same time? Both server side?

Comment: Thanks I found it EnableClientScript="false"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create a javascript function and hook up the customvalidators via OnClientValidate, so that it will fire client side with the requiredfieldvalidators.

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k(VS.71).aspx

Comment: The client would prefer me not to use javascript

Comment: do you disable the client side validation on the required field validator? Becuase, I think if you did, they would all fire at the same time - after a postback

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do that. Is there a property?

Comment: Thanks I found the property EnableClientScript="false"